# How to setup redirects for a large number of posts

Tags: redirect, migration, subdomain

I am working on a major site migration for alpinezone.com . As part of that migration, I moved all the news articles from vbulletin into wordpress cms. The vbulletin articles were previousyl pulled out via a plugin called GARS.

In any event, I have 3400 news articles over the course of five years or so. They are presently in the following format:

news.alpinezone.com/12345

If the title of the news article was "Sugarloaf Sets World Record" then the new location will be

alpinezone.com/sugarloaf-sets-world-record/

Is there a way for me to automate creating the necessary redirects that take the title from the literal page 12345 and convert into a URL?

Finally; the additional trick is that since I did a VB upgrade the existing news articles no longer show up. So going to news.alpinezone.com/12345 won't show anything right now, you need to pull up the forum thread (which is typically hidden) by taking that identifier and going to http://forums.alpinezone.com/showthread.php?12345 to see the actual title. I can pull all this from the WP database, (since all the posts are from a user AlpineZone News).

Any ideas? I'm fairly new to this and the added complexity of subdomains is somethign I am trying to figure out. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could make your own showthread.php file in the correct location it was previously located.

have it use the passed id, retrieve the associated record from your database.

Construct the new url by turning the title to [lowercase](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) and [changing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) spaces to - and do a redirect via [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)('Location: *new url here*');

Comment: Thanks Harald, I was able to extract all the articles and tie them together so now what I have is a full list of the OLD pages and a full list of the NEW pages I just need to figure out what to do with that now Is it OK to have an .htaccess file with over 3500 entries? Finally anything special I need to do because of the subdomain?

Comment: why would you want to do it like that? Your old known URI have a specific pattern that search engines know and link to, just make sure the pattern exists (so keep (sub)domain/possible_dirs/your_target_file.php or redirect with a single .htaccess rule) and let that endpoint handle the logic and redirect. Search engines will learn from the redirect and adapt their URI. A good idea might be to built a linkmap to help them do this, so they don't miss older/rarely asked links.

Comment: Even though the new URl's are completely different? They aren't the same structure. In other words it used to be alpinezone.com/12345 and now it's alpinzone.com/some-news-article.